# Synchronization between updating the UI and touch event in Android

Tags: android, multithreading, synchronization, touch, handler

In my Activity, there is a periodical task which updates the UI and its information and that task is periodically posted on a UI handler. But at the same time, my Activity must implement onTouchEvent() and handle touch events appropriately depending on the UI information. My concern is a synchronization between input (touch event) and a task run by the system. For example, while my app is updating the UI and didn't finish it, onTouchEvent() interrupts the updating task and the whole app might go crazy.

So basically my question is, are tasks posted by handler and onTouchEvent() atomic? By atomic, I mean when you are running a function, it will not be interrupted until it finishes. If they are all atomic, it's silly for me to worry about all these cases. If they are not, what would be a good solution for this?

Comment: Yes, they are. There's only *one* UI thread, so if you're posting a `Runnable` to the UI thread, it will complete before processing touch events.

Comment: Thank you very much. So is it safe to think every Runnable object posted by the ui handler is atomic to each other?